# Nested Class with get only property

Tags: c#, class, inner-classes

assuming that i have below class:

```
public class ClassA 
{
    public string ElementA { get; }
    public string ElementB { get; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public ClassA ElementC = new ClassA()
    {
        ElementA = "Sample Value A",
        ElementB = "Sample Value B"
    };

    public ClassB ElementD = new ClassA()
    {
        ElementA = "Sample Value C",
        ElementB = "Sample Value D"
    };
}
```

how can i nest ClassA inside and as an element of ClassB with only a `{ get; }` property. I am trying to instantiate a class where it can only be accessed via the `{ get; }` assessor as i want it to behave as a fixed variable/value. the IDE (Visual Studio) throws me an error whenever i try this approach which states:

[image]

> Property or indexer 'ClassA.ElementA' cannot be assigned to -- it is
>   read only

writing ClassA as:

```
public class ClassA 
{
    public string ElementA { get; set; }
    public string ElementB { get; set; }
}
```

makes ClassB's ClassA Element editable but does not throw an error in the IDE (Visual Studio).

how or is it possible to do something of my idea ? Thanks.

Comment: try a constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the properties modified from outside of the class, add a private setter and modify the class's constructor to set the values upon instantiation:

```
public class ClassA 
{
    public ClassA(string elementA, string elementB)
    {
        ElementA = elementA;
        ElementB = elementB;
    }

    public string ElementA { get; private set; }
    public string ElementB { get; private set; }
}
```

Then instantiate it from `ClassB` like this:

```
public class ClassB
{
    public ClassA ElementC = new ClassA("Sample Value A", "Sample Value B");
}
```

Comment: this answered my question. Thank you @Grant !

Comment: As of C# 6 you don't need to add a private setter.

Answer (score 2):

A property defined like this:

```
public Foo Bar { get; }
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
private readonly Foo bar;

public Foo Bar { get { return this.bar; } }
```

The `readonly` keyword means the field can only be assigned in a class's constructor (or the field initialization list, which is executed before the constructor method's body).

Because the field is private, you cannot set it from outside the type's access scope, and because it's a `readonly` field it must be in the constructor - so to use an externally-provided value you must use a constructor parameter:

```
public ClassA(Foo value) {
    this.Bar = value;
}
```

Comment: well explained. will keep this in mind and will save this for my future reference. thank you @Dai !